# Overwriting the default style while using primeng in angular2

Tags: angular, primeng

I am building an application using angular2 webpack. I am using Primeng's datatable to display data.I am trying to change the color of the selected row. I found out that "ui-state-highlight" is the class that is getting added when the row is selected, but i am unable to override this class. I tried to do it in my "global.less" but still it is not overwriting it. could some one help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add !important after any css rule you wish to override:

eg:

```
.ui-state-highlight{
    background-color: salmon !important;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i did the same thing and it was not working, but now i found out that i have given the wrong hex code for the background-color (typed #cfe2f**s** instead of #cfe2f**5**). Your answer helped me out in debugging.